Observations in TWAP Uniswap
In Uniswap v3's TWAP oracle, how often are observations stored in the observations array of each pool (assuming the array's cardinality has been increased several times already)?
Is it on every swap?
I'm not sure this is it since I've seen some pools (like rETH-ETH) that at some point it had only 150 slots in the array and there were observations with months of difference between them.
